# Calcular monto restante de cada cuota, dependiendo del numero de cuotas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero calcular el monto restante después de cada cuota acá esta parte del código en la parte de "Formas de pago" es donde quiero hacerlo, al seleccionar la cantidad de cuotas se generan las filas con el monto de la cuota y el monto restante que es que quiero calcular pero no he podido

[image: Acá tengo el html, donde en select se selecciona la cantidad de cuotas a pagar]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // var doc = new jsPDF();
  // var specialElementHandlers = {
  //     '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
  //         return true;
  //     }
  // };

  // $('#btn-pdf').click(function () {   
  //     doc.fromHTML($('#tab_pre').html(), 40, 40, {
  //         'width': 1000,
  //             'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
  //     });
  //     doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
  // });
  // 
  // 



  // function cargarselectmat(){
  //  $(".selecmat").val("");
  //   var select = "bienes";
  //   var estacion = $(".")
  //   $.ajax({
  //    url:"sql/select.php",
  //    type:'POST',
  //    dataType:'json',
  //    data: {
  //     select:select,

  //    },
  //    success: function(response)
  //    {
  //      $('.selecmat').html(response);
  //    }
  //  });
  // }



  // $("#add").click(function(){



  //     var tds=$("#tab_pre tr:first td").length;
  //     // Obtenemos el total de columnas (tr) del id "tabla"
  //     var trs=$("#tab_pre tr").length;
  //     trs = trs - 1; 
  //     var tr = "tr";

  //     var n = trs + 1;
  //  var selectubicacion=('<select name="" id="selubc'+n+'" class="form-control form-control-sm selecestac"></select>');
  //  var codigodelbien=('<select name="" id="selcodbn'+n+'" class="form-control form-control-sm seleccodbn"></select>');
  //  var cantidad=('<input type="text" id="cantidad'+n+'" class="form-control form-control-sm">');
  //  var descripcion = ('<input type="text" id="desc'+n+'" class="form-control form-control-sm">');
  //  var material = ('<select name="" id="selmat'+n+'" class="form-control form-control-sm selecmat"></select>');
  //  var precio = ('<input type="text" id="precio'+n+'" class="form-control form-control-sm">');
  //  var pre = ('<input type="text" id="meses'+n+'" class="form-control form-control-sm">');
  //  var total = ('<input type="text" id="total'+n+'" class="form-control form-control-sm">');
  //  var ancho = ('<input type="text" id="ancho'+n+'" class="form-control form-control-sm">');
  //  var alto = ('<input type="text" id="alto'+n+'" class="form-control form-control-sm">');

  //     var nuevaFila="<tr id='"+tr+""+trs+"'>";
  //     for(var i=0;i<tds;i++){
  //         // añadimos las columnas
  //         // nuevaFila+="<td>columna "+(i+1)+" Añadida con jquery</td>";
  //     }
  //     // Añadimos una columna con el numero total de columnas.
  //     // Añadimos uno al total, ya que cuando cargamos los valores para la
  //     // columna, todavia no esta añadida

  //     nuevaFila+='<td><h6>'+n+'</h6 ></td>';
  //     nuevaFila+='<td>'+selectubicacion+'</td>';
  //     nuevaFila+="<td>"+codigodelbien+"</td>";
  //     nuevaFila+="<td>"+cantidad+"</td>";
  //     nuevaFila+="<td>"+descripcion+"</td>";
  //     nuevaFila+="<td>"+material+"</td>";
  //     nuevaFila+="<td>"+(trs+1)+"</td>";
  //     nuevaFila+="<td>"+(trs+1)+"</td>";
  //     nuevaFila+="<td>"+precio+"</td>";
  //     nuevaFila+="<td>"+meses+"</td>";
  //     nuevaFila+="<td>"+total+"</td>";
  //     nuevaFila+="</tr>";

  //  $("#selubc"+n+"").val("");
  //   var select = "estaciones";
  //   $.ajax({
  //    url:"sql/select.php",
  //    type:'POST',
  //    dataType:'json',
  //    data: {select:select},
  //    success: function(response)
  //    {
  //     $("#selubc"+n+"").html(response);

  //    }

  //  });

  //     $("#tab_pre").append(nuevaFila);

  // });




  // $("#remov").click(function(){

  //  $("#tab_pre tr:last").remove();
  // });

  $("#ubic").val("");
  var select = "estaciones";
  $.ajax({
    url: "sql/select.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      select: select
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#ubic").html(response);

    }

  });


  $("#mat").val("");
  var select = "materiales";
  $.ajax({
    url: "sql/select.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      select: select
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#mat").html(response);

    }

  });





  $("#codb").blur(function(event) {
    var accion = "buscar_bien";
    var bien = $("#codb").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'sql/gst_pre.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          bien: bien,
          accion: accion
        },
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        if ((data.result) = 1) {
          $("#anc").val(data.anc);
          $("#alt").val(data.alt);
        }
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
      })
      .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
      });

  });

  $("#meex").change(function(event) {
    var total;
    var meses = $("#meex").val();
    var pre = $("#pre").val();
    total = parseFloat(meses * pre);
    $("#total").val(total);
  });


  $("#btn-actualizar").click(function(event) {

  });

  $("#add").click(function() {
    // && $("#desc").val()!=""
    // if ($("#ubic").val()!="" && $("#codb").val()!="" && $("#codb").val()!="" && $("#cant").val()!=""  && $("#mat").val()!="" && $("#anc").val()!="" && $("#alt").val()!="" && $("#pre").val()!="" && $("#meex").val()!="" && $("#total").val()!="") {
    addData();
    // }else{
    //  swal("Error!", "Para poder generar mas columnas es necesario \n No dejar campos vacios", "error");
    // }

    function addData() {
      var tds = $("#tab_pre tr:first td").length;
      var trs = $("#tab_pre tr").length;
      //var sum= 0;
      var suma = 0;
      var n = trs - 2;
      trs = trs - 2;



      var markup = "<tr id='tr" + n + "'>";

      var dat = $("#ubic").val();
      var ubic = dat.substr(1);

      var codb = $("#codb").val();
      var cant = $("#cant").val();
      var desc = $("#desc").val();

      var mat = $("#mat").val();
      mat = mat.substr(1);

      var anc = $("#anc").val();
      var alt = $("#alt").val();
      var pre = $("#pre").val();
      var meex = $("#meex").val();
      var total = $("#total").val();

      markup += "<td width='4%'><input type='checkbox' class='form-control' name='record'></td>";
      markup += "<td>" + n + "</td>";
      markup += "<td>" + ubic + "</td>";
      markup += "<td>" + codb + "</td>";
      markup += "<td>" + cant + "</td>";
      markup += "<td>" + desc + "</td>";
      markup += "<td>" + mat + "</td>";
      markup += "<td>" + anc + "</td>";
      markup += "<td>" + alt + "</td>";
      markup += "<td>" + pre + "</td>";
      markup += "<td>" + meex + "</td>";
      markup += "<td class='total'>" + total + "</td>";

      markup += "</tr>";

      $("#tab_pre tbody").append(markup);
      for (var i = 0; i < trs; i++) {

        //  $('#tab_pre .total').each(function(){

        //   sum = parseFloat($(this).text()); 

        //  });
        // suma = suma + sum;
      }
      //alert(suma);
      //$("#sub-total").val(suma);

      $("#ubic").val("");
      $("#codb").val("");
      $("#cant").val("");
      $("#desc").val("");
      $("#mat").val("");
      $("#anc").val("");
      $("#alt").val("");
      $("#pre").val("");
      $("#meex").val("");
      $("#total").val("");
    }
    calcular();
  });





  function calcular() {

    var suma = 0;
    $(".total").each(function() {
      suma += parseFloat($(this).html()) || 0;
    });
    $("#sub-total").val(suma);

  }



  // Find and remove selected table rows
  $("#rmv").click(function() {
    $("#tab_pre tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
      }
    });

    calcular();
  });


  // $("#btn-actualizar").click(function(event) {

  // var table = $("#tab_pre").html();
  // alert(table); 
  // });


  $("#cuotas").change(function(event) {

    $("#pagos tbody tr").remove();

    var cuotas = $("#cuotas").val();
    //var subtotal = $("#sub-total").val();




    var tds = $("#pagos tr:first td").length;
    var trs = $("#pagos tr").length;
    var j = 0;
    var n = trs;
    var res = 0;

    var subtotal = 1000;
    var resul = (subtotal) / (cuotas);

    for (var i = 0; i < cuotas; i++) {
      j = j + 1;

      res -= resul;
      //alert(res);
       var row="<tr>";
       row += "<td width='4%'>"+j+"</td>";
       row += "<td>Cuota "+j+" de "+cuotas+"</td>";
       row += "<td>"+resul+"</td>";
       row += "<td>"+res+"</td>";
       row += "<td>HI4</td>";
       row +="</tr>";

      $("#pagos tbody").append(row);

      //alert("sub" +subtotal+ "resul" +resul+ "rest" +rest+ "res" +res );
    }






  });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <!-- Favicons -->
  <!--     <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./assets/img/kit/free/apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" href="./assets/img/kit/free/favicon.png"> -->
  <title>
    Sistema de Comercialización
  </title>
  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">

</head>

<body class="bg-light">

  <?php include("nav/nav.php"); ?>


  <div class="container">

    <div class="card card-nav-tabs">
      <!--       <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
        Featured  
      </div> -->
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">Gestión de presupuestos</h2>
        <p class="card-text">
          <!-- Nombre -->
        </p>


        <form action="#" accept-charset="utf-8" id="gst_pre">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
              <label for="buscador">Buscar</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm alfa" id="buscador" placeholder="Buscar presupuesto">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="buscar">Buscar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
              <label for="cod">* Código</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm codigo" id="cod" placeholder="Código del presupuesto" disabled>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
              <label for="fecha">* Fecha</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="fecha" placeholder="Fecha de elaboración">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
              <label for="dur">* Duración</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="dur" placeholder="Lapso de negociación">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
              <label for="cod">* Nombre del Anunciante</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm codigo" id="cod" placeholder="Nombre del anunciante" disabled>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
              <label for="cod">* RIF</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm codigo" id="cod" placeholder="Rif" disabled>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
              <label for="cod">* Exp</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm codigo" id="cod" placeholder="Código del expediente" disabled>
            </div>

          </div>
        </form>


        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" style="font-size: 11px" id="tab_pre">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col" width="4%">Check</th>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col" width="15%">Ubicación</th>
              <th scope="col" width="14%">Código del bien</th>
              <th scope="col" width="5%">Cantidad</th>
              <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
              <th scope="col" width="15%">Material a utilizar</th>
              <th scope="col">Ancho (M)</th>
              <th scope="col">Alto (M)</th>
              <th scope="col" width="10%">Precio Mensual</th>
              <th scope="col" width="5%">Meses a Exhibir</th>
              <th scope="col" width="10%">Total</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="4" class="text-right">TOTAL:</th>
              <td>
                <input type="text" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
              </td>
              <th colspan="6" class="text-right">SUB-TOTAL</th>
              <td>
                <input type="text" id="sub-total" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <!-- <input type='checkbox' name='record'> -->
              </th>
              <th scope="row"></th>
              <td>
                <select id="ubic" class="form-control form-control-sm"></select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" id="codb" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" id="cant" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" id="desc" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              </td>
              <td>
                <select name="" id="mat" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" id="anc" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" id="alt" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" id="pre" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" id="meex" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" id="total" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Agregar</button>
          <button id="rmv" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-group col-lg-12">
            <label for="imp">Importe total en letras: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 ">
            <h6>Formas de pago del servicio:</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group col-lg-3 offset-lg-6">
            <label for="imp">Cantidad de cuotas: </label>
            <select name="" id="cuotas" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                    <option value="" selected>seleccione</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                  </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" id="pagos" style="font-size: 11px">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col" width="5%">#</th>
              <th scope="col" width="20%">Concepto</th>
              <th scope="col" width="20%">Monto</th>
              <th scope="col">Monto restante</th>
              <th scope="col">Fecha correspondiente de pago</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <!--             <tr>
              <td width='4%'>1</td>
              <td id="concepto"></td>
              <td id="monto"></td>
              <td id="monrest"></td>
              <td id="fechpag"></td>
            </tr> -->
          </tbody>
        </table>



        <div class="col-lg-auto text-center" style="font-size: 12px">
          IVA Y COSTO DE PRODUCCION NO INCLUIDO
          <br> Estos espacios están sujetos a cambio sin previo aviso

        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-center" style="font-size: 12px">
            <label for="elab_by">Elaborado por:</label>
            <input type="text" id="elab_by" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="T.S.U José Velíz">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="Analista de Negocios B">
          </div>

          <div class="col text-center" style="font-size: 12px">
            <label for="revi_by">Revisado por:</label>
            <input type="text" id="revi_by" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="T.S.U Luzmary Lacruz">
            <br> <input type="text" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="Coordinadora de Negocios">
          </div>

          <div class="col text-center" style="font-size: 12px">
            <label for="apro_by">Aprobado por:</label>
            <input type="text" id="apro_by" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="Ing. María Carrabs">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="Gerente de  Mercadeo y Comercialización">
          </div>

        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-lg-auto text-center" style="font-size: 12px">
          Av. Sesquicentenaria, Parque Recreacional Sur, Parte Sur Oeste S/N Zona Valencia Sur, Estado Carabobo Venezuela, Telf. +58(241)8740400 al 8740410. www.metrovalencia.gob.ve

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button id="btn-guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Guardar</button>
      <button id="btn-actualizar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Actualizar</button>
      <button id="btn-pdf" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">PDF</button>
    </div>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    

    <!--<script defer src="script/validador.js"></script>
 <script defer src="script/select.js"></script> 
<script defer src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

<script defer src="script/gst_pre.js"></script> -->



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes calcularlo de la siguiente manera suponiendo que ya posees el valor del monto y la cantidad de cuotas:

**EDIT**
Vi la parte de tu código donde haces el calculo y actualice acorde a tu código.

```js
$("#cuotas").change(function(event) {

    $("#pagos tbody tr").remove();

    var cuotas = $("#cuotas").val();
    var subtotal = $("#sub-total").val();

    var resul = subtotal / cuotas;

    for (var i = 0; i < cuotas; i++) {

       var res = subtotal-resul*(i+1);

        var row="<tr>";
        row += "<td width='4%'>"+(i+1)+"</td>";
        row += "<td>Cuota "+(i+1)+" de "+cuotas+"</td>";
        row += "<td>"+resul.toFixed(2)+"</td>";
        row += "<td>"+res.toFixed(2)+"</td>";
        row += "<td>HI4</td>";
        row +="</tr>";

       $("#pagos tbody").append(row);

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cuotas">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="subtotal" id="sub-total" value=10000>
<div id="pagos">
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>concepto</th>
  <th>monto</th>
  <th>monto restante</th>
  <th>fecha pago</th>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Saludos!